# SSR - Angular Universal 9 loading my root twice and hanging

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular9, angular-universal

I'm trying to find why my code is binding root two times using Angular 9 SSR.

I tried eventReplayer.replayAll() trick but I'm still stuck, I noticed when I'm scrolling into the page finally I'm getting the the proper root loaded perfectly and the other one removed (ng-non-bindable), so I removed `PrebootModule` just to narrow the issue and I got one root in my dom but the application won't run properly.

[image]

**app.component.ts**

```
BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'dcaa'}),
PrebootModule.withConfig({appRoot: 'dcaa-root'}),
.
.
.
{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: function (document: HTMLDocument, platformId: Object): Function {
        return () => {
          if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
            const dom = getDOM();
            const styles: any[] = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('style[ng-transition]'));
            styles.forEach(el => {
              // Remove ng-transition attribute to prevent Angular appInitializerFactory
              // to remove server styles before preboot complete
              el.removeAttribute('ng-transition');
            });
            document.addEventListener('PrebootComplete', () => {
              // After preboot complete, remove the server scripts
              setTimeout(() => styles.forEach(el => dom.remove(el)));
            });
          }
        };
      },
      deps: [DOCUMENT, PLATFORM_ID],
      multi: true
    }
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'disabled',
    relativeLinkResolution: 'corrected',
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
    initialNavigation: 'enabled'
  }),
```

**app.server.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule,
    FlexLayoutServerModule
  ],
```

**main.ts**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with preboot when I was was trying to manipulate the DOM during ngAfterViewInit on the browser side, this cause PrebootComplete to not fire properly because the DOM has changed.

The fix is to inject **EventReplayer** in your component:

```ts
import { EventReplayer } from 'preboot';
```

```js
constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
    private replayer: EventReplayer
  )
```

And then replay preboot events:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      // ....
      // Manipulate your DOM here 
      // ....

      this.replayer.replayAll()      
    }
  }
```